# MySQL Select Query Difference between 5.0 and 5.5

Tags: mysql

The following query is being used on MySQL 5.0.95 and 5.5.30.

On 5.5.30 it returns the proper result (1 results).

On 5.0.95 it returns the proper result but with a duplicate. So it's returning it twice (2 results).

I haven't seen anything in documentation that would cause this.

```
SELECT
  job.job_id, job.job_number, job.status, job_applicants.job_id, 
  job_applicants.user_id, job_applicants.accepted, 
  job_declined.job_id, job_declined.user_id, job_declined.declined
FROM job
    JOIN job_applicants ON job.job_id = job_applicants.job_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN job_declined ON job.job_id = job_declined.job_id
WHERE 
    job_applicants.user_id = 6 AND job_applicants.accepted = 0 
    AND job.job_id NOT IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT job_id FROM job_declined WHERE user_id = 6 and declined = 1)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in 5.0 that was fixed in a later version. That's the point of new versions.

Comment: Do both queries return the same value for the inner SELECT DISTINCT query?

Comment: I don't remember such a bug being documented in 5.0. But it sounds like DISTINCT would fix it, right?

Comment: @kojow7 Yes, exact same fields and data are returned

Comment: @Strawberry Believe it or not, removing `AND job.job_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT job_id FROM job_declined WHERE user_id = 6 and declined = 1)` still shows same duplicate results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the LEFT OUTER JOIN of job_declined. That did not need to be joined in the first query, only in the sub-query. Apparently, 5.0.95 minded.

```
SELECT
  job.job_id, job.job_number, job.status, job_applicants.job_id, 
  job_applicants.user_id, job_applicants.accepted
FROM job
    JOIN job_applicants ON job.job_id = job_applicants.job_id
WHERE 
    job_applicants.user_id = 6 AND job_applicants.accepted = 0 
    AND job.job_id NOT IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT job_id FROM job_declined WHERE user_id = 6 and declined = 1)
```

Comment: I don't understand. This is a different query

Comment: @Strawberry This is the same query. I removed all job_declined data from the first SELECT query. I then removed the JOIN in the first query `LEFT OUTER JOIN job_declined ON job.job_id = job_declined.job_id`  I didn't need to pull job_declined data in the first, only needed to in the sub-query.

Comment: We have different definitions of 'same'